# Access SQL Query: Display only most recent record of duplicate records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a query that will filter a table and then only display the most recent record for each respective `TRIM Reference ID`.

I'm making a update status system and want to only list the most recent status of for each particular `TRIM Reference ID`. Each time a TRIM Reference ID has a new status, it is issued a unique ID for that particular update. Therefore I know that I can use the highest ID for determining which record to display in my output table.

| ID | TRIM Reference ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 100 |
| 3 | 100 |
| 4 | 120 |
| 5 | 120 |
| 6 | 100 |

Output to look like

| ID | TRIM Reference ID |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 120 |
| 6 | 100 |

I want the output to be a table with each '`TRIM Reference ID`' with it's most recent ID

I've tried, but an error :

> "Your query does not include the specified expression 'ID' as part of
> an aggregate function.

```sql
SELECT [ID], [TRIM_Reference_ID], Max(ID)
FROM UpdateStatus
GROUP BY [TRIM_Reference_ID]
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: If one of these great answers solved your problem then please make sure to press the tick next to the best answer to mark it as the solution. In addition to saying it was the solution the answerer will get rep and you'll also get a tiny amount too.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    max(ID) ID,
    [Trim reference id] Trim_Reference_ID
from
    ['Duplicate Data$']
group by
    [Trim reference id]
order by
    ID;
```

Comment: Hrmm, it comes back with - 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'max(ID) ID'.

Comment: kindly rename your table and columns without any spaces and rewrite your question and your query.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I've edited my question and changed the table name to UpdateStatus and field to TRIM_Reference_ID.

Answer (score 0):

This is error is because of using a `GROUP BY` expression without defining all the fields that you are using on the `SELECT` statement that aren't an **aggregate** function (MAX, SUM, COUNT, etc), as explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/group-by-clause-84eeb766-25d2-4aa1-8eea-002bb65ef3a0).

To solve it, you need to add to the `GROUP BY` expression all the fields that you use in the select statement that are **NOT** an aggregate function. Or only return in the `SELECT` the ones that you want to **Group by**. Like this:

```sql
SELECT [TRIM_Reference_ID], Max(ID) ID
FROM UpdateStatus
GROUP BY [TRIM_Reference_ID]
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Hi Douglas, thanks for your help, but your code doesn't appear to produce the output that's required. I'm after an output that removes the duplicate rows and only keeps the most recent update for each TRIM_Reference_ID

Comment: Hi @helfelf, I have edited the answer. in case the MAX() is not returning the maximum ID, are you sure that the ID field its a number and not a string?

Comment: Hi Douglas, yes the 'data type' is 'AutoNumber', also now the error is coming up "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Max(ID) ID'. "

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire row, use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM UpdateStatus as u
WHERE u.id = (SELECT MAX(u2.id)
              FROM UpdateStatus as u2
              WHERE u2.TRIM_Reference_ID = u.TRIM_Reference_ID
             )
ORDER BY ID;
```

There is no need to fetch the id in one query and then fetch the rest of the row in another query -- which sounds like the approach you are taking.